# htaccess redirect all of a filetype

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hello I am really bad at understanding how .htaccess and mod_rewrite works.

I would like all requests to a `.html` file to be redirected to a `php` file which renders out the requested page. How would I do this, so all page requests like `example.com`, `example.com/index.html`, `example.com/test.html` would all be redirected (internally handled) by index.php?

I tried this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L,R=301]
```

But it didn't change a thing?

Comment: The problem was that I also has `disallow from *.html` in .htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `R` flag otherwise browser will redirect to `.php` URL:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]
```